# Identify me from the pictures

Tags: visual, rebus, knowledge

I am a thing.

I am helpful to everybody.

Identify me from the following pictures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hint:

> I am not available in these pictures. But my name can be formed using the words drawn from the above pictures.

Comment: Is it a four letter word? like letter from each word drawn from the above pictures? Or is the answer is related to the words drawn from the above pictures?

Comment: Try to extract words from each picture..Then it takes you to final answer.

Comment: Did you put this through sandbox?

Comment: @smriti **This isn't a riddle.** Only questions that are tagged [riddle] have to be sandboxed.

Comment: @Mithrandir I did not no that! I was wondering about the same. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: I thought it might be a defibrillator; the upside-down A might mean "the last" (as "A" is the first), the vegetables and fruit might mean health, and the opposing magnets might mean force or pushing (as they are matched to push against each other) so: the last resort for sustaining life/health by using force is a defibrillator. But the password picture doesn't match

Comment: @Sathi Reddy  When you say in your hint that the name can be formed using the words, does that mean the words are related in some way or they form like a phrase?

Comment: I added another answer, check it out

Comment: Hmm, interesting rebus....

Answer (score 4):

I am a thing.

I am helpful to everybody.

Answer:

> I am a metal or rock

First picture

> Maths Symbol 'For all'

Second picture

> Vitamin C. Combining with first picture - **All at Sea**

Third picture

> Lock and Key

Fourth picture

> Adore//Repel

Relation between each of them

> All are Metal bands / Rock bands

Comment: @ramboo and smriti almost to final answer.

Answer (score 3):

**This was my first attempt**
Does it represent(and I know that I can be majorly wrong)

> iron

First picture(symbol of A upside down)

> symbolic meaning 'For all'

Second picture(bunch of fruits and vegetables)

> Source of iron

Third picture(Lock)

> Can be made up of iron

Forth picture(magnets attraction)

> Adore//Repel (credits : @ramb00 )

**This is my next answer**
Getting all the clues from above explanation and with the help of clues from @ramb00

> All the things are made of iron/ all are bands... So is the answer **"Iron Maiden"**

Comment: The magnets seem to be wrongly matched, where same poles push away instead of attracting. I think that it the main concept of the last picture, so I don't think this is the answer

Comment: @nine9 My bad!! I did not see that(excited to write answer)

Comment: Giving answers are exciting, I don't blame you :p

Answer (score 3):

My Answer:

> A Moderator.

First Image:

> As interpreted by many people, it represents an upside down A meaning "for all" or "given any"

Second Image:

> It shows fruits and vegetables correlating to Vitamin C.  C -> See (homophones)

Third Image:

> It looks like a password or security system on a phone.

Fourth Image:

> Looks like a magnetic field or repelling magnets.

Conclusion

> The phrase that I get is *Given any (For All) ___  See (C) security field (field security).  The blank could hold the word moderator because field security settings let you restrict users' access to view and edit specific fields.